# Removing ~/tmp folder removed all data and reset Mac OS X 10.10 (Mavericks)

Tags: macos, mac, data-recovery, osx-yosemite

I was trying remove data from my own created temp folder under home directory but I accidently ended up deleting default “tmp” directory under home `~/tmp`. And to my deepest shock it wiped out pretty much everything! Nothing in “Trash.” All my documents, downloads, pictures, projects. GONE!

I dont have time machine back up as well. but I dont understand what the hell happen when I deleted that `tmp` folder! I remember it used to have some `npm-*` files/folders. How the hell it got power to wipe out everything? Of course I used `sudo` but so do I used it millions times at work on linux and this never happened. 
How do I recover from this?

This was the command that wreaked havoc

```
sudo rm -rf * tmp/
```

Comment: It’s probably not critical in this situation, but: why are you using `sudo` to remove files from your own directory? “I run `sudo` in front of _every_ command” is a ***very bad*** habit to get into – the operating system provides protections against doing harmful things, and `sudo` disables much of that protection. “If a command fails, I automatically try it again with `sudo`” is just as bad – if a command fails, you should figure out _why_ it failed, and, if it’s a permissions/privileges issue, figure out whether you really want to be doing that (overriding the OS’s protection mechanisms).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You state you wanted to delete the contents of this: `~/tmp`. But the command you say you ran is this:

```
sudo rm -rf * tmp/
```

Sorry to say that all of the contents of the directory you were in when you ran this command—most likely your home directory—were wiped out when you ran that command.

The command you *should* have run is this:

```
sudo rm -rf ~/tmp
```

By running that first command, this is what went wrong:

1. You had a wildcard (`*`) character which basically means “Act on everything from this directory including child directories.”
2. There is a space between the `*` and `tmp/`, which makes no sense.
3. The way `rm` works is it will delete any items in the space delimited list that it was provided with. So when you ran `sudo rm -rf` with `* tmp/`, it basically told the system to “Act on everything from this directory including child directories and then when that is done, delete the `tmp/` directory after that.” 
   And, of course, the `-r` told `rm` to search through your child directories *recursively*.

So when all is said and done… Yes… You told Mac OS X—via the “Terminal”—to delete all files and directories from whatever directory you ran that command in.

Also you say this:

> Nothing in “Trash.” All my documents, downloads, pictures, projects.
>   GONE!

The “Trash” plays no role in the “Terminal” since the whole “Trash” concept is a safety-net part of the Mac OS X “Finder” system. When you delete something in the “Finder” it goes into the “Trash”, but if you run `rm` from the “Terminal” the item(s) are deleted and gone. Unless you have a backup the stuff is gone. Sorry. Nothing can be done.

This is why, in the world of the command line—and acting on files like this—it is *always* recommended that you do a “dry run” command with [`ls`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/ls.1.html) (list directory contents) like this:

```
ls -la * tmp/
```

Since `ls` just lists files and directories, by running the `ls -la` with `* tmp/` to begin with, you will get a listing of all of the files and directories that the `* tmp/` arguments would act on. And—in some alternative scenario—you would immediately see what the command might do if you ran it with `sudo rm -rf` command and know, “Hey! That seems wrong…” and jump back to the drawing board to see how to reproach your cleanup effort.

Comment: any suggestion on how to recover this kind of lost? I am actually trying out recovery softwares now.. DiskDrill seemed to identify lost files. I feel little better now. but damn what a punishment!

Comment: thanks for suggestion. I'm gonna follow it religiously. This was heart dropping experience! First thing I am gonna do is turn that time machine on and sync it to my external hdd. For now, looks like Disk Drill have found few hundred gigs of my data. It may save my ass looks like this time

Comment: Don't let it scare you away from the command line forever, though -- it's an extraordinarily powerful tool. Backup often, do some research before running commands, and keep learning.

Answer (score 0):

If your working directory was your home directory, you deleted all the contents of your home directory, because you specified `*`, which is everything in the current directory. Since there was a space, `tmp/` was read as another argument, but that has no effect as `*` deleted everything.

Now all you can do is search for hard drive recovery software.